# Laravel 419 , page expired

Tags: laravel-backpack

After installing backpack v6, getting 419 | page expired error, I can't go to any other page with getting the page expired error, I tried to put the  on the blank.blade.php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndWs8.png)

After creating the models and installing backpack devtools

Comment: Answered you in https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/552

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `APP_URL` in `.env` file.

> APP_URL=https://example.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same problem.

If you are serving from localhost with `php artisan serve`, then set in your `.env` file:

`APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000`

See this [backpack Github issue for an explanation](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/community-forum/issues/552#issuecomment-1621341478)